# Xcode running Apigee sample gives PushNotification.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apigee

I have been going through Apigee's push notification tutorial: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/tutorial-push-notifications-sample-app

When I do step 4 and try and run in Xcode I get a compilation error 'PushNotification.h not found'. I cannot find anywhere how/where this code is supposed to be installed.

Anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: Have you #include -ed PushNotification.h in your header or implementation file?

Comment: There is a #import "PushNotification.h" in the AppDelegate.m file but the PushNotification.h file doesn't exist. I am thinking I must have missed a step somewhere in the Apigee tutorial to install this code but as hard as I look I cannot find any information on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download the sample app properly? I would do that again. I also realized PushNotification.h is in [Apigee Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). Check this -

https://github.com/apigee/appservices-phonegap-push-plugin/tree/master/src/ios

Sometimes you just remove the reference of the library and add reference again. Eventually, give [remus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1214800/remus)'s suggestion a chance, he's the API & app maker at Apigee.

Comment: Thanks raurora, I think my confusion comes from the instructions that say the plugin is included with the sample but the sample plugin directory is empty. I guess I need to install manually and your link should help me there.